# SQL выборка по датам от текущего времени

Tags: sql, postgresql

Дано, простая таблица table1 (name integer, date timestamp) PG

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу вывести все данные, где date менее 1 дня от текущего времени. Т.е. если сейчас 3.10.21 00:00, хочу получить все записи от 2.10.21 00:00 и старше.
Пробовал через CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, там только интервал нагуглил... select * from table1 where date > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '1 day'

Answer (score 0):

типа того?

```
select * from table1 where date> current_timestamp::date - interval '1 day';
```

Comment: В таком случае интервал же будет не полный день? Т.е покажет результат 2021-10-04 00:00, при применении скрипта допустим в 2021-10-04 17:00

Comment: current_timestamp::date кастит штамп времени в дату, а - interval '1 day' вычитает 1 день. т.о. 2021-10-04 17:00 при касте ::date станет 2021-10-04, а после - interval '1 day' получится 2021-10-03, и select вернет все значения у которых дата > 2021-10-03 00:00:00